# How to color td when i click and swipe?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have a test `div` that i can drag into a table when the `div` is dropped into the tab i color the target `<td>` in blue. 
Now i would like to make all other td beeing colored when i click, hold and swipe to the right or left side of the blue one `<td>` like resizing.

So my question is:
How to "resize" my blue `<td>`?
"Resize" is not the good word because i want to simulate it doing coloring the others `<td>` by clicking and swiping to the right or left side like a resize if you have a clue/way to follow i will be thankfull.

i try to use jquery ui resizable to put the `div` directly in the `td` but i can't make what i want with it (i think?)

Please have a look at the code snippet, it is hard to explain what I want to get from jQuery.

thanks by advance

```js
$(function () {
            // There's the gallery and the trash
            var $job = $("#testblocks"),
                $ressource = $(".ressource");

            // Let the gallery items be draggable
            $("div", $job).draggable({
                cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
                revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
                containment: ".containment-wrapper",
                helper: "clone",
                cursor: "move",
                snap: "td",
                scroll: false,
                refreshPositions: true,
                drag: function () {
                    var offset = $(this).offset();
                    var xPos = offset.left;
                    var yPos = offset.top;
                    /*$('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
                    $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);*/
                }
            });
            /*$("div", $job).resizable({
                handles: 'e, w',
                containment: ".containment-wrapper"
            });*/

            $ressource.droppable({
                hoverClass: 'hovering',
                tolerance: 'pointer',
                accept: "#testblocks > div, .ressource div",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    //$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
                    $(this).css("background-color", "blue");
                    $(this).next("td").css("background-color", "blue");
                    $(this).next("td").next("td").css("background-color", "blue");
                    $(this).next("td").next("td").next("td").css("background-color", "blue");
                }
            });

            $job.droppable({
                accept: ".ressource div",
                classes: {
                    "ui-droppable-active": "custom-state-active"
                },
                drop: function (event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).appendTo($job);
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.drag {
            height: 49px;
            width: 60px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        td {
            border: 1px solid black;
            /*height:50px;*/
            width: 160px;
        }

        th {
            border: 1px solid black;
            /*height:50px;*/
            width: 180px;
        }

        tr {
            border: 1px solid black;
            height: 150px;
        }

        .basr {
            height: 150px;

        }

        .masterContent {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
    <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
        <th style="border:1px solid black;"></th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">Lundi</th>
        <th style="border:1px solid black;">Mardi</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Ressource 1</th>
        <td colspan="6" rowspan="4" class="masterContent">
            <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;width:100%;" class="containment-wrapper">
                <tr>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    <td><table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                            <tr style="border:0;">
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                                <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table></td>
                    

                </tr>
                <tr class="basr">
                    <td colspan="26" id="testblocks">
                        <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr drag">
                            test
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Ressource 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="basr">
        <th>bac à sable</th>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So what is not working in your code? How do we replicate it or test it? Dopes this happen on any specific browsers?

Comment: You're also missing a `<thead>` element.

Comment: hi, i don't know how to "resize" my blue `<td>`. resize is not the good word because i want to simulate it doing coloring the others `<td>` on clicking and swiping to the right or left side like a resize if you have a clue/way to follow i will be thankfull .
And yes, you true i forget the `<thead>` ...
the code snippet work to test what i do actually.

Comment: Sounds like after it is dropped, you want to have a "ghost" element be resized and then "fill in" the cells below it.

Comment: Many thanks for your response.
not a ghost,, my dropped element is a calendar event, i want to resize this event.
To resize it i need to color the next or previous `<td>` with the same colour when i click and hold the right or left border of the couloured cell (`<td>`) with (if it's possible) the resize cursor...

Comment: Should there be any containment? Should they only be able to resize a specific amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what I was suggesting. As you can't resize the Cells, you will need to lay something over to act as a representative. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  // There's the gallery and the trash
  var $job = $("#testblocks"),
    $ressource = $(".ressource");

  $("div", $job).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon",
    revert: "invalid",
    containment: ".containment-wrapper",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    snap: "td",
    scroll: false,
    refreshPositions: true,
    drag: function() {
      var offset = $(this).offset();
      var xPos = offset.left;
      var yPos = offset.top;
      /*$('#posX').text('x: ' + xPos);
      $('#posY').text('y: ' + yPos);*/
    }
  });

  $ressource.droppable({
    hoverClass: 'hovering',
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    accept: "#testblocks > div, .ressource div",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      //$(ui.draggable).appendTo($(this));
      var i = $(this).index();
      var p = i - 1;
      var n = i + 1;
      var t = $(this);
      var r = t.parent();
      t
        .add($("td", r).eq(n))
        .add($("td", r).eq(++n))
        .add($("td", r).eq(++n))
        .addClass("marked");
      n++;

      $("<div>", {
        class: "ghost for"
      }).css({
        width: t.width(),
        height: t.height()
      }).appendTo("body").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(".marked:first", r)
      }).resizable({
        handles: "w",
        resize: function(e, ui) {
          if (ui.position.left < $("td", r).eq(p).position().left) {
            $("td", r).eq(p--).addClass("marked");
          }
          ui.size.width = t.width();
        }
      });

      $("<div>", {
        class: "ghost aft"
      }).css({
        width: t.width(),
        height: t.height()
      }).appendTo("body").position({
        my: "left top",
        at: "left top",
        of: $(".marked:last", r)
      }).resizable({
        handles: "e",
        resize: function(e, ui) {
          var f = ui.position.left;
          if (ui.position.left < $("td", r).eq(n).position().left) {
            $("td", r).eq(n++).addClass("marked");
          }
          ui.size.width = t.width();
        }
      });
    }
  });

  $job.droppable({
    accept: ".ressource div",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-active": "custom-state-active"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $(ui.draggable).appendTo($job);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.drag {
  height: 49px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*height:50px;*/
  width: 160px;
}

th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  /*height:50px;*/
  width: 180px;
}

tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 150px;
}

.basr {
  height: 150px;
}

.masterContent {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.marked {
  background-color: blue;
}

.ghost {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0" style="border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
  <thead>
    <tr style="border:1px solid black;">
      <th style="border:1px solid black;"></th>
      <th style="border:1px solid black;">Lundi</th>
      <th style="border:1px solid black;">Mardi</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Ressource 1</th>
      <td colspan="6" rowspan="4" class="masterContent">
        <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;width:100%;" class="containment-wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                  <tr style="border:0;">
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                  <tr style="border:0;">
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                  <tr style="border:0;">
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                  <tr style="border:0;">
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
              <td>
                <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                  <tr style="border:0;">
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                    <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table cellspacing="0" style="border:0;">
                <tr style="border:0;">
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                  <td style='border:0;' class='ressource'></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>


          </tr>
          <tr class="basr">
            <td colspan="26" id="testblocks">
              <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr drag">
                test
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Ressource 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="basr">
      <th>bac à sable</th>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

We use a Class to simply mark the Cells or highlight them. We also add psudeo handles that are not a part of the Table. As we resize the, we can retain the size but just look at the postioning to identify which cells to mark as we move in one direction.

Comment: Hi Twisty, this is really cool and near what i am looking for i will try to do this for decrease the size (resizing down?) too.
I have now only one big problem and i don't know why, when i resize by the left side that continue to resize in the same block by the right side  i need to pass hover the parent `td` to extend my "event"

Comment: I can't modify this part of the code correctly:
`if (ui.position.left < $("td", r).eq(p).position().left) {
                                    $("td", r).eq(p--).addClass("marked");
                                }`

I must be able to extend my event beyond the left border big `td` with the "containment" class...
@Twisty could you help me?

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: @Fangster what you are asking is exceptionally more difficult based on your HTML Structure. Now, if you need to target the next cell, or previous cell, this is easy to do with the same table. Selecting the cell in another table becomes much more difficult.

Comment: Okay i will try to change the html structure and keep the same "view" many thanks for your response!

Comment: I try what you said about HTML structure but i have a problem with the resize i don't know why but colored `td` not follow the cursor when i resize. Here you can see my entire code:
https://lite1.infini.fr/p/r.0404332391578bcb62c9b775c7384f8d

you just need to put the code in a php file and run it.

Comment: now i can resize by the left side but i still have a problem with the right i don't know why but the `ui.position.left` never change and just a little move of the cursor color a lot of `<td>`...